# Phaser Lighting issues

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I'm using the phaser webgl lighting

```js
this.lights.enable();
this.lights.setAmbientColor(0x808080);
this.spotlight = this.lights.addLight(2040, -200, 20000).setIntensity(20);
```

I'm trying to cover really large distance, seen in that 20000px radius, basically an in-game sun, and I face the issue of actually making the large area bright, but not have the issue of the intensity making it so bright at the top that you can only see white over there

[image: Ground being dark]
[image: sky too bright]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want a lighting effect, the easy way like by all 2D games is to fake it. There is a [brilliant article](https://%20https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-day-night-cycle-in-phaser/) on how to make a day/night cycle in phaser, it is abit dated, but it explains exactly how you can achieve this.

And more or less something like, discribed in the article is a easy and good solution. Basiclly:

- the sun is just an image
- the darkness and brightness can be achieved with overlays and alpha values (use gradients in the overlays if you want a fading effect)

Comment: This Article changes the background in a tween, which I'd rather not do

Comment: Is there any way to get partially transparent camera overlays?

Comment: @VatsaPandey I dont 100% sure I understand, but you can create an graphic object, draw on it and set the alpha value on the graphics object. or an image and also set the alpha.  Or use a mask https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/display/masks , depending on your usecase